# No handlers could be found for logger "OpenGL.arrays.arraydatatype"

Tags: pyopengl, pyinstaller

On my Windows 7 machine, I used pyinstaller to convert my python program into an exe.

However, I got the above error when trying to run the exe.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this problem was caused by OpenGL_accelerate. add it as hiddenimports